# Best way to structure code when using asynchronous methods (e.g. auth retrieval)?

Tags: android, asynchronous, firebase, callback, firebase-authentication

I'm working on an Andriod app. I was examining my work from a high-level perspective, and there seemed to be a very high branching factor of potential [auth-based] crashes that could occur stemming from the fact that authorization is asynchronous using Firebase.

My attempt at solving this (simplistically put) was to put pretty much all my code into the callback of the Firebase auth result (but then I had issues with race conditions related to the Google API Client [I use location] connection callback, along with other small issues).

After doing what I could to make it as watertight as possible, I'm a little dissatisfied with the way my code is laid out in my project. E.g. In my MainActivity's `onCreate` method, I wish I could just lay everything out linearly to be executed one after the other (but I am aware of the UX drawbacks of not having things being done asynchronously).

Given this, I'm wondering if anyone knows of any better ways to do this or best practices when it comes to this sort of thing. Is the best solution just to put all the code into the callbacks of methods on which it depends? Or is there something I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes there is , your structure is asynchronous in nature.To avoid race conditions every condition must trigger accordingly. The glorious concept of promises perfectly does this job for you.Promises return an object…which promises to do some work.This object has separate callbacks…for success and failures.

This let's us work with asynchronous code…in a much more synchronous way.…A really nice feature is that promises…can be combined into dependency chains. Which simply means execute this, if that happens or fail that. Please consider using rxjava or rather rxandroid which embodies the notion of observable.Observables can be used to model events, asynchronous requests, and animations.

Observables can also be transformed, combined, and consumed.
is the best solution just to put all the code into the callbacks of methods on which it depends? well like you said it depends , what you should is to separate tasks into single dependencies not one big monolithic callback.

Comment: Some paragraphs might be nice.

Comment: "separate tasks into single dependencies" the issue is there are overarching dependencies that the rest of my code hinges on like user authentication, so it turns into a really messy chain of callbacks. i'll look into your suggestions, thanks for the input.

Comment: exactly no further action should be taken unless the authentication dependency is fulfilled get what i mean?